# How can i convert NSString to NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

How can i convert NSString to NSDate?

from these Strings:

```
    NSString *year = @"2010";
NSString *month = @"3";
NSString *day = @"12";
```

to change UIDatePicker.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` can turn a string into a date. You create an `NSDateFormatter` object, set its format using `setDateFormat:` and then use its `dateFromString:` method to convert a string into a date.